# How can I use CSS to responsively transition from a top nav to a fixed-bottom nav

Tags: css, angularjs, navbar, ejs, responsive

I'm working on a node application using angular and ejs.  The nav is an ejs input series of radio buttons at the top of the app on desktop.  What I'd like to do is just use CSS to move and fix it to the bottom on mobile without having to create a second redundant navbar and then worry about hiding and showing each.  Is there a way to do accomplish this. Code below.

```
<input  name="tab" type="hidden" ng-model="stt"  ng-init="stt= '<%=defaulttab%>' "   >
     <input  name="tabss" type="hidden" ng-model="isLoggedIn111"  ng-init="isLoggedIn111= '<%=isLoggedIn%>' "   >
     <input  name="tabss" type="hidden" ng-model="navlist111"  ng-init="navlist111= '<%=navList%>' "   >



    <div ng-show = "isLoggedIn" class="segmented-control" >



         <% for(var i=0; i<navList.length;i++){%>

        <input type="radio" id="<%=navList[i].id%>" 



         ng-model="tabname" value="<%=navList[i].value%>"  ng-change='tabSelected(value)' >

        <label for="<%=navList[i].id%>" class="sc-label"><%=navList[i].text%></label>   

         <%}%>
```

```
        <input type="radio" id="sc-arrival"  ng-model="tabname" value="arrival"  ng-change='tabSelected(value)' >
                <label for="sc-arrival" class="sc-label">Arrival/Departure </label> 



        <input type="radio" id="sc-table"    ng-model="tabname" value="table" ng-change='tabSelected(value)' >
                <label for="sc-table" class="sc-label">Table Maintanance </label>       

        <input type="radio" id="sc-schAlert" ng-model="tabname" value="schalert" ng-change='tabSelected(value)'>
                <label for="sc-schAlert" class="sc-label">Schedule Alert </label>

        <input type="radio" id="sc-svcAlert" ng-model="tabname" value="alerts" ng-change='tabSelected(value)'>
                <label for="sc-svcAlert" class="sc-label">Service Alert </label>    

            -->
    </div>
```

Comment: When you say fix it to the bottom, do you mean for it to be position fix so it is always at the bottom no matter what part of the page you are on? If so then what is the actual issue you are having?

Comment: Since you want to use CSS only it would help to see your CSS code. If you want it fixed to the bottom have you tried using position: absolute; ?

Comment: The issue I'm having is that I want, perhaps through media queries for instance, to switch the nav from top to fixed at the bottom.  Is it as simple as doing position fixed bottom on a media query?

Comment: Yes, just use a media query, I would suggest staring mobile first and over writting the styles that need to change on larger screens.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm modding an app someone else did, so having to build down from desktop.  I think I was making things a lot harder than they had to be.